# Compiling ES6 arrow functions to Es5 using Babel.js

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, babeljs, lexical-scope

While looking into ES6 arrow functions' documentation on Mozilla documentation, I got to know that Arrow functions applies all the rules of strict mode, except one as described in the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Relation_with_strict_mode)

```html
  var f = () => { 'use strict'; return this};
    var g = function () { 'use strict'; return this;}

    console.log(f()); //prints Window
    console.log(g()); // prints undefined

    //we can test this in firefox!
```

But, `Babel.js`is transpiling the arrow function code to ES5 code that returns `undefined` rather than `Window`([demo link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20this%3B%0A%7D%2C%20100)%3B))

```js
"use strict";

setTimeout(function () {
  return undefined;
}, 100);
```

So, the above snippet is the output from Babel.js. Couldn't it be the below output?

```js
"use strict";

setTimeout(function () {
  return this;
}.bind(Window), 100);
```

If I am writing ES6, I would expect `Window` rather than `undefined`
Is it a bug?
 OR, I misunderstood anything?

Comment: Babel puts everything in strict mode. `undefined` looks correct.

Comment: @elclanrs It is correct from ES5 perspective since code is transpiled to ES5, but in case of arrow function in ES6 it should be `window`.

Comment: @dfsq why should it be window? It would be inheriting `this` from the encapsulating object, which isn't defined; not the global.  Or am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Babel assumes every file is a *module*. Modules are *strict* by default and their `this` value is `undefined`.

---

This is covered in the [Babel FAQ](http://babeljs.io/docs/faq/#why-is-this-being-remapped-to-undefined-):

> Babel assumes that all input code is an ES2015 module. ES2015 modules are implicitly strict mode so this means that top-level `this` is not `window` in the browser nor is it `exports` in node.
>
> If you don't want this behaviour then you have the option of disabling the strict transformer:
>
> ```
> $ babel --blacklist strict script.js
>
> require("babel").transform("code", { blacklist: ["strict"] });
> ```
>
> PLEASE NOTE: If you do this you're willingly deviating from the spec and this may cause future interop issues.
>
> See the [strict transformer docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/other/strict) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in principle, as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Relation_with_strict_mode). However, Babel always places a `'use strict'` at the root scope. In effect you compile the following:

```
'use strict';
var f = () => { 'use strict'; return this};
```

In that case strict rules *do* apply. See the compiled example [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20f%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20'use%20strict'%3B%20return%20this%7D%3B%0Avar%20g%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20'use%20strict'%3B%20return%20this%3B%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(f())%3B%20%2F%2Fprints%20undefined%0Aconsole.log(g())%3B%20%2F%2F%20prints%20undefined%0A). Babel even optimizes away the top-level `this` as it is guaranteed to be `undefined`.

Comment: That is what I am doubting... I expect the output to be `Window` and writes my code... So, how could it be valid?

Comment: @Navaneeth When `'use strict'` is the first statement in a script, the global `this` object becomes undefined [(see here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript). This also applies to other blocks where this inherits from the global scope. Try e.g. `(function() { console.log(this); }) ()` and `(function() { 'use strict'; console.log(this); }) ()`. Since Babel operates entirely in strict mode, its compiler correctly assumes `this` is undefined in the global scope. If you want to access the  `window` object, just do it explicitly.